# Determine Performance and Observation window

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, classification, data-processing

I have 3 years historical transaction dataset since jan'2016 - dec'2018. I want to make classification model of good and bad customer. Before do that, I need to make observation window and performance window of my data to determine my features and target (good or bad).

If the condition of bad customer is somebody who did not do transaction in 6 months. **how the best way to make observation window and performance window?**


I have thought that to make performance window at july'2018-dec'2018 (6 month). So I can get all features (predictors) at range (jan'2016 - jun'2018) then see the customer is bad (target) if they do not do transaction in range of performance window.

Do you think that I am thinking a right method or not? or have I an misuderstanding about performance or observation window? Thank you for your help.